# Indexing documents in ElasticSearch with PHP curl

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to add documents to ElasticSearch.  I have no problems using curl from the command line, but I'm having trouble when using curl in PHP.  I'm following this example from the docs:  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/index_.html

The following code is giving me this error:  `{"error":"IndexMissingException[[twitter] missing]","status":404}`

```
$search_host = '127.0.0.1';
$search_port = '9200';
$index = 'twitter';
$doc_type = 'tweet';
$doc_id = 1;

    $json_doc = array(
                "user" => "kimchy",
                "post_date" => "2012-11-15T14:12:12",
                "message" => "trying out Elastic Search"
            );
    $json_doc = json_encode($json_doc);

    $baseUri = 'http://'.$search_host.':'.$search_port.'/'.$index.'/'.$doc_type.'/'.$doc_id;

    $ci = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUri);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_PORT, $search_port);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'XPUT');
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_doc);
    $response = curl_exec($ci);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use XPOST instead of XPUT?

Comment: Yes, the error is the same with XPOST, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to set the the curl option `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to `PUT`, not `XPUT`.

```
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
```